# Swift NSWindow fixed position

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I am creating an OSX App in Swift.

What I want is: when I press the icon in the mac top bar I want the window to be exactly underneath the icon like most preferences app do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the mouse when the user clicks the statusbar and then you know where you can put your window:

```
NSEvent.mouseLocation()
```

Comment: Where in NSMenu can I see when a user clicked on the icon?  Not on the title.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257848/left-vs-right-click-status-bar-item-mac-swift-2