# What does the single | mean in swift

Tags: swift, macos

I found some example code when building a menu bar item in OS X. It makes use of the single | and I'm unsure what it actually means.

(What I'm trying to do is have a function called on left click of the menu item, but have it show the menu on right click)

Here's my code

```
//Get reference to main system status bar
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)
statusItem.image = icon
statusItem.menu = menuBar
if let statusButton = statusItem.button
{
    statusButton.target = self
    statusButton.action = #selector(statusItemClicked)

    statusButton.sendActionOn(Int(NSEventMask.RightMouseUpMask.rawValue | NSEventMask.LeftMouseUpMask.rawValue))

}
```

Original Answer with code [Left vs Right Click Status Bar Item Mac Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257848/left-vs-right-click-status-bar-item-mac-swift-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That must be really old code. Nowadays, in modern Swift, [NSEventMask is an Option Set](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nseventmask). You can just say `[NSEventMask.rightMouseUp, NSEventMask.leftMouseUp]`, and you don't need the Int cast at all. (Or if you haven't updated to Swift 3 yet, the case names would start with capital letters.)

Comment: For more information on bitmasks, the old way (your way) of dealing with them and the new way (Option Sets), see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionsSets

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise OR, just like it does in most C-like languages. In this context, it's being used to combine flags.

Comment: Do you understand exactly what its doing in this code? Im going to do a bit more research on it. This code doesn't actually work and I'm unsure if thats the issue.

Comment: @Dallas It is old code and should be rewriten, like matt said. Take a look at the link from his (very good) book