# Menu Bar icon clicked on and runs a function

Tags: swift, swift3, macos-sierra, nsmenuitem

I was wondering if someone could help me out with a bit of syntax.

I have a menu bar app that I would like to run a function then the icon is clicked.

I have tried messaging about with this syntax with left click right click but it first runs the function and dent open the menu.
Is there a way to make it run the function as well as open the menu at the same time?

Miles

Comment: 1. What exactly is your question? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. Where are you stuck? 4. Post code.

Comment: Basically I would like to be able to run a function when the Menu bar button of the app is clicked on. 

I have been using this as a basic guide for my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257848/left-vs-right-click-status-bar-item-mac-swift-2 

However when I first click on the menu bar button it will run the function without opening the menu, then if i click it again it will open the menu.

I would like it to open the menu and run the function, is that possible?

Comment: use multi threading.  you can run multiples process at one time...you can use this    DispatchQueue.main.async {your code }

Comment: How would I do that?

Inside the applicationDidFinshingLaunching i am stating 

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: "myImage")
            statusItem.menu = statusMenu
           queryState()
        }

Where queryState is a function to check the state of the screen and the collect the output from the pipe as a string